# Split a String on 2nd last occurrence of comma in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split

I have a string say

```js
var str = "xy,yz,zx,ab,bc,cd";
```

and I want to split it on the 2nd last occurrence of comma i.e

```js
a = "xy,yz,zx,ab"
b = "bc,cd"
```

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by mixing few methods, just like that:

```js
const str = "xy,yz,zx,ab,bc,cd";
const tempArr = str.split(',');
const a = tempArr.slice(0, -2).join(',');
const b = tempArr.slice(-2).join(',');

console.log("a:", a, "b:", b);
```

Comment: Why revert your answer, when my changes improved this and was testable? `tempArr.slice(0, tempArr.length - 2)` can be written `tempArr.slice(0, - 2)`

Comment: There is no need to improve answer, which doesn't contain any spelling mistakes nor formatting issues.

Comment: There is also no harm to make code more elegant and easier to read and you could at least  keep the snippet.

Comment: @mplungjan maybe you're right, I've rolled back to your improvement, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use regex:

```js
var str = "xy,yz,zx,ab,bc,cd";

const [a, b] = str.split(/,(?=[^,]*,[^,]*$)/);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: I have a simpler one - any functional differences? `/(.*),(.*,.*)$/`

Comment: Yours is using group capturing to capture both groups as results. Mine is to find the delimiter and split it into two parts. They are the same concept but different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex

```js
var str= "xy,yz,zx,ab,bc,cd"


const parts = [,a,b]=str.match(/(.*),(.*,.*)$/)

console.log(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

counting from back:

```
let str = "xy,yz,zx,ab,bc,cd";
let idx = str.lastIndexOf(',' , str.lastIndexOf(',')-1);
str.slice(0, idx);
str.slice(idx + 1);
```